# Why is spyder console responding inappropriately?

Tags: python, console, spyder

I have installed spyder v3.0.2 as part of Anaconda (in Windows 7), and have started working through the tutorial.

However, the python console does not seem to be responding correctly to input, either directly in the console or from a script via runfile.

There seem to be two things going on:

(1) The prompt appears too quickly so that it cuts into output

[image: Spyder output 1]

(2) Each time my script (which defines a hello function including one call to print, and calls it) is run, I do not see the expected output until I press `Enter`. From then on the console seems to need me to press `Enter` another time to produce the normal response you would expect from `Enter`. This leads to unexpected behaviour, particularly around the regular (`>>>`) and continuation (`...`) prompts. It increments each time the script is re-run, so that after running three times you need to press `Enter` an additional three times. For example:

[image: Spyder output 2]

Am I missing something obvious? My guess would be that it has something to do with line ending encodings but I can't figure out how to stop it. Also to my mind that still wouldn't explain issue (1).

Note that the IPython console seems to work without these issues (which of course I can use but I don't like the fact that there is clearly something amiss more generally...). Also, I tried installing the Mac version on my MacBook and don't have the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Was fine in Spyder 2. This happens in 3.0.1 as well.

Comment: Glad it's not only me :-)

Comment: What happens if you go to `Preferences > Python Console > External modules > Graphics > Backend` and select `None` there? Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a partial fix, after restarting spyder ("apply" was not sufficient by itself!). The more problematic issue #2 is now gone. But I am still seeing issue #1, namely the premature prompt - any ideas?

Comment: No idea. The Python console is essentially broken on Windows because of these ugly bugs that I have no idea how to fix. So please don't use it for now and use the IPython console instead. My plan is to remove the Python console in Spyder 4.0.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I'm experiencing the same issue. I can confirm that spyder 2.3.9 doesn't have this issue. Using Ipython console is not a good option for me, since one important feature of Spyder is being able to have lots of dedicated python console running under one spyder instance.

Comment: @jf328, sorry to hear that, but the Python console is on the way out, unless the community steps up and fixes its multiple problems.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Would we then have an option to "run in a dedicated IPython console" when F5 a script?

Comment: @jf328, yes, we'll add to Spyder 4.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: just for the record, ipython has the same problem in spyder 3.1.4 (anaconda 4.3.1), on windows 7.